# tkinter deprecation warning in mba m1 2020

Tags: macos, tkinter, apple-m1

DEPRECATION WARNING: The system version of Tk is deprecated and may be removed in a future release. Please don't rely on it. Set TK_SILENCE_DEPRECATION=1 to suppress this warning.

why is this showing while making gui in mba m1 2020? The GUI app shows a blank screen while running the program.

what should I do now?

```
import tkinter as tk

def button_click():
    label.config(text="Button Clicked!")

# Create the main window
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Simple GUI")

# Create a label
label = tk.Label(window, text="Hello, Tkinter!")
label.pack(pady=10)

# Create a button
button = tk.Button(window, text="Click me!", command=button_click)
button.pack(pady=10)

# Run the main loop
window.mainloop()
```

according to my code, it must show  "button clicked!"
but showing me only this [interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIcde.png) even after clicking the button

Answer (score 0):

**Issue:**

Hi there bv29, you are facing the issue because your version of Tkinter must be outdated or you are using the built-in Mac python version, which is going to be deprecated soon.

**Solution:**

```
pip3 install --upgrade tkinter
```

If this still doesn't work try checking your python version by using the following command:

```
python -V
```

If you don't have latest python install which is 3.12.1, since you are on Mac download it from here: Python [3.12.1](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.12.1/python-3.12.1-macos11.pkg)

**Proof:**
Your same code on my MacBook is giving me the output below.

Before pressing the button:

[image: Before button is pressed]

After button is pressed:

[image: After button is pressed]

Comment: Note that `tkinter` cannot be installed via `pip3` (or `pip`).

Comment: Hi there @acw1668, I think you should be checking that out on the web, here's an example: [Tkinter Python Installation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-install-tkinter-in-python#:~:text=To%20install%20Tkinter%2C%20we%20need,need%20not%20install%20it%20separately.)

Comment: Sure the web is wrong.  Can you find tkinter in pypi.org which pip uses to install modules? Also there are several times mentioned this in questions in StackOverflow.